# CORS with SPServices + jQuery

Tags: 2013, javascript, jquery, spservices, ajax

I need to access from a different domaine on a mobile a sharepoint list. Here is my code, a simple get request :

```
$.support.cors = true;

$(function() {
$().SPServices({
    operation: "GetListItems",
    webURL: "http://myurl.com/project/",
    listName: "PM-Registration",
    CAMLQuery: '<Query></Query>',
    error: function (xhr, message, error) {
          alert('error : ' + error);
    },
    completefunc: function (xData, status) {
        alert('Status: '+status+' xdata: ' + xData.statusText);
        alert('RESPONSE: ' + xData.responseText);
    }
});
});
```

The problem seems to be CORS blocking the request, but I normally enable it before.
It works perfectly with Chrome if I use the command : --args --disable-web-security, and with Safari desktop, but not with Firefox and Safari iOS...
I got the error on Chrome without disabling web security :

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource
```

Am I missing something ? I guess it is a client side problem as it works with Chrome without web security and Safari Desktop

Answer (score 1):

Your webURL isn't correct. It probably should be just `http://myurl.com/project`. You're pointing to the owssvr.dll services, which doesn't have any meaning in an SPServices context.

Comment: Thanks you for your answer ! Then how can I target the correct list if it's  not in the URL ?

Comment: You use the listName and webURL combination, as you are doing. You don't need to worry about CORS if you are requesting data within the same Site Collection. In fact, if that's the case, you should use a relative URL, like "/project".

Comment: I didn't say it but in fact I am on an other domain and I can't change the server seetings (corporate rules....). I deleted the list in the URL but still this CORS error...

Comment: Thanks for your answer again, I edited my question with my last test.

Comment: Getting same error, did you find any solution?

Comment: Works in IE by the way.